# What is wrong with this self-made array shuffling algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, randomness

I'm aware of the established array-shuffling algorithms, such as Knuth-Fisher-Yates. I'm interested in proving (or disproving) that my self-made shuffling algorithm is broken. It seems to be the reverse of KFY and requires the same number of random numbers. Here's the algorithm:

`for i from 0 upto n-1 do:
  j = random integer such as that i ≤ j ≤ n-1;
  exchange a[j] and a[i];`

**Extra:** If this algorithm is indeed the reverse of KFY and working, are there any general properties, something like "the reverse of a random shuffling algorithm is also random shuffling"?

Comment: This *is* KFY.  You quote, almost *verbatim*, the account given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm.  The sole difference is that you can stop when $i==n-2$ because when $i==n-1$ you will invariably interchange the last element with itself, which accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @user5226582 I don't see at all how this is a duplicate, since the algorithm in question is completely different!

Comment: @whuber I don't understand why this is KFY, since my interval for the random number j is different. Could you please explain why the interval doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: Your interval for $j$ is *identical* to the one in the Wikipedia article, which is (I am cutting and pasting here) "i ≤ j < n".

Comment: @whuber Ooops, sorry!